# Segmentation Fault in Trie implementation in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a trie data structure to spell-check a given text file. Currently, it seems to work for a couple words in the file, then it reaches a seg fault. I tried debugging to find the culprit, but all I found was that the value of "letter" is retaining seemingly random negative values (it should be between 1 and 27, inclusive). Normally the seg fault issue appears almost instantly after i start the program, so I'm not sure why the issue is popping up in the middle of the program.

```
    /**
     * Implements a dictionary's functionality.
     */

    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    #include "dictionary.h"


    //create global root node
    Trienode *root;
    //create word counter for size() function
    unsigned int wordcount = 0;

    //creates an empty node
    Trienode * newnode()
    {
        Trienode *nnode = NULL;
        nnode = (Trienode *)malloc(sizeof(Trienode));
        //initialize new node with null pointers and values
        nnode -> parent = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            nnode -> children[i] = NULL;
        }
        return nnode;
    }

    void cleartrie(Trienode *head)
    {
        //if child node exists, free it, else continue with next iteration in for loop
        if(head)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
            {
                cleartrie(head -> children[i]);
            }
            free(head);
            head = NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
     */
    bool check(const char *word)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int letter;
        Trienode *head = root;

        while(word[i] != '\0')
        {
            if(isalpha(word[i]))
            {
                letter = word[i] - 'a';
            }
            else //it must be an apostrophe
            {
                letter = word[i] - 13;
            }
            if(!(head -> children[letter]))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else //a pointer must exist
            {
                head = head -> children[letter];
            }
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
     */
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
    {
        //open file
        FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
        Trienode *parnode; //parent node
        root = newnode();
        Trienode *curnode = root; //current node

        int letter = 0;
        //while not end of file, read words
        while(fgetc(infile) != EOF)
        {
            //while not end of word, read letters
            for(;;)
            {
                int c;
                //read current letter in file
                c = fgetc(infile); 
                //convert input char to corresponding array location (a - z = 0-25, apostrophe = 26)
                if(isalpha(c))
                {
                    letter = c - 'a';
                }
                else if (c == '\'')
                {
                    letter = c - 13;
                }
                //if end of string, exit loop
                else if (c == '\0')
                {
                    //end of word, so endofstring = true
                    wordcount++;
                    break;
                }
                //move to next letter if not either apostrophe or alphabetical
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                //if pointer to letter of word doesn't exist, create new node
                if(curnode -> children[letter] == NULL)
                {
                    curnode -> children[letter] = newnode();
                }
                //child node is the new current node
                parnode = curnode;
                curnode = curnode -> children[letter];
                curnode -> parent = parnode;

            }
            //return to root node
            curnode = root;
        } 

        fclose(infile);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
     */
    unsigned int size(void)
    {
        return wordcount;
    }

    /**
     * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
     */
    bool unload(void)
    {
        cleartrie(root);
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Sorry about the wall of text, but most of it is just there for context (I hope). The seg fault error is occurring on the if(!(head -> children[letter])) line of the check helper function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see what a Trienode is in your code. Is it a struct?

Comment: Did you use a debugger? At what points in your code exactly does the set fault occur (the debugger should tell you)? Where do you see that the value of `letter` goes awry? Since this is partial code listing (and I wouldn't suggest putting all your code in without narrowing down the problem) it's hard to say where the problem is just "looking" at it. Do more debugging and narrow it down.

Comment: Use valgrind.  It will tell  you where your problems are.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be written with spaces on either side.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your test file may contain some uppercase letters. If this is the case, then subtracting `'a'` in an attempt to remap your letters will result in a negative number, since `'A' < 'a'`. Have a look at the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). Converting the letters to lowercase first should solve your problem.